# Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, document.write

I'm having a problem with javascript. I'm trying to create a button that will cause some content to load over on top of what I got. I created some functions to do this. It works perfectly if I test the function on the HTML page if the script is already loaded, however, when I use an onclick event to call the function, it just creates an entirely new .html page with the content in it.

I know this because I saved the page it created, then I viewed the source, and it was just a blank page with the contents of the javascript function written in the body tag.

Here is the HTML.

```
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li onclick='articleRead("test", DeviantArtUpdateContent)'><a href="#Deviant Art Update">Deviant Art Update</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">'Triumph At Last' Album Preview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Short Funny and Stupid</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project Preview</a></li>

            </ul>

<div id="aID"></div>
```

Here is the javascript.

```
function articlePopUp   ( title , content)  {
document.write('<div class="backgroundFade"></div>');
document.write('<div class="articlePosition"><div class="closeArticle">Close</div>');
document.write('<div class="articleRead">');
document.write('<h1>');
document.write(title);
document.write('</h1>');
document.write('<div class="grey-line"></div>');
document.write(content);
document.write('</div></div>');
}
function articleRead ( title, content)  {
    document.getElementById("aID").innerHTML=articlePopUp(title,content);   
}
```

Like I said before, if I just call the function in the HTML document without an onclick event it works the way I intended, but adding the onclick event creates a blank document when I click it. I want to write the function into the existing document in the intended div id. Thanks ofr any help in advance, this really gots me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` will blank out your entire page if it is called after the page loads. You probably want to use `innerHTML` instead.

```
function articlePopUp( title , content)  {
    htmlContent = '';
    htmlContent += '<div class="backgroundFade"></div>';
    htmlContent += '<div class="articlePosition"><div class="closeArticle">Close</div>';
    htmlContent += '<div class="articleRead">';
    htmlContent += '<h1>';
    htmlContent += title;
    htmlContent += '</h1>';
    htmlContent += '<div class="grey-line"></div>';
    htmlContent += content;
    htmlContent += '</div></div>';
    return htmlContent;
}
function articleRead ( title, content)  {
    document.getElementById("aID").innerHTML = articlePopUp(title,content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the page has finished loading, it enters a *closed* state.

Calling `document.write` on a closed document will implicitly call `document.open` which will start a new document.

You don't want to add the content to the document inside `articlePopUp` anyway. You are trying to assign its return value to an `innerHTML` property. Since there isn't an explicit return value, that is `undefined` (and the element doesn't exist anyway for the aforementioned reasons).

Have your function build a string and return it.

```
var html = '<div class="backgroundFade"></div>';
html = html + '<div class="articlePosition"><div class="closeArticle">Close</div>';
// etc
return html;
```

Better yet, use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement), [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode), [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) and friends.

Comment: Could you comment on why its better to use createElement than setting innerHTML?

Comment: The usual reasons for gluing components together with functions instead of mashing up strings: It's clearer, less error prone and takes care of escaping for you.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: You neednt mash the strings too much - you can put line breaks instead of concatenating over and over, and you could argue that a block of nicely formatted html is more readable than a long list of createElement/appendChildNode/setAttribute calls. Browsers are good at html parsing too so theres not really a speed issue. Just wanted another opinion - not trying to start an argument :)